# AngularJS cdvfile プロトコルでバインドが使えない

Tags: monaca, angularjs, filesystems

Monacaを使ったアプリ作りに挑戦しています。
やりたいことは、cdvfile プロトコルでアプリ内サンドボックスの画像を表示しようとしています。
そこで、以下のようなソースがあるのですが、上部の直接指定した場合、問題なく表示出来ました。
次に、場所を動的に作成したかった為、バインドさせようと下部のように試してみたところ、画像が表示されませんでした。
これは仕様なのでしょうか？
分かる方居ましたら、よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
　　<html ng-app="myApp">
　　　　<head>
　　　　　　<meta charset="UTF-8" />
　　　　</head>

　　　　<body ng-controller="test">
　　　　　　<div>
 　　　　　　　<img src="cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/image/test.jpg" />
　　　　　　</div>

　　　　　　<div>
 　　　　　　　<img src={{dir}} />
　　　　　　</div>

　　　　　　<script>
　　　　　　　　angular.module('myApp', [])
 　　　　　　　　　.controller('test', function($scope){
                    $scope.dir= "cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/image/test.jpg";
                  }]);
           </script>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: すみません、自己解決しました。

ソースを見たところ、src unsafeとあったため、セキュリティポリシーがおかしいのではないかと思い、見直しました。
content="default-src 'self' この間のスペースを消したところ、上手く動作しました。
スペースが入ることで上手く動作しない理由はよく分かりませんが、きちんと表示されました。
失礼しました。

Comment: 自己解決されたとのことなので、ご自身で回答を書かれると今後同じような問題で悩まれる方の役に立つかと思います。ご一考ください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。改めて回答を書かせていただきました。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。
ソースを良く見てみると、src unsafeとあった為、画像が表示できませんでした。
cdvfileを使う際はセキュリティポリシーを設定しないといけない、と各サイトにありますが、Monacaを参考に設定すると上手く動作せず。

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

この、fefault-src 'self' の間にあるスペースを消すことで、認識してくれました。
ここは動作しない原因がわからず、本当に苦労しました・・・。

さらに認識させるにはもう人工夫が必要で、

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.config(function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(cdvfile|file):|data:image\//);
});
```

ホワイトリストにcdvfileを追加しないといけませんでした。
なお、このconfigを追加してしまうと、ローカルsrcが認識しなくなった為、fileを追加しています。
詳しい動きは不明ですが、これで解決しましたので、今度参考になればと思います。