# セキュリティポリシーが動作しない

Tags: javascript, monaca, angularjs

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35350/angularjs-cdvfile-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84?noredirect=1#comment35108_35350)にて、cdvfileプロトコルを使いたいという事で一旦自己解決したのですが、これをAndroidで使おうとした際、別のエラーとなりました。
Monacaにある例のどおり、

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

こちらを指定すると、

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'default-src'
>   contains an invalid source: 'gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com'. It
>   will be ignored.

このようなエラーが出ます。

次に、前回の解決策のように、スペースを消してみました。

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

そうすると、次のようなエラーが出て、認識できなくなりました。

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'default-src'self''.

こちらも色々調べてみましたが、解決出来ない為、詳しい方、お力添えをお願いします。

Comment: Monacaのドキュメントを参考にされている場合、ドキュメントのリンクを提示しておくと回答がつきやすいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回からの参考にさせて頂きますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

おそらくMonacaの[このページ](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/file/#cdvfile-protocol)のドキュメントを参考にされたものとして回答します。
ドキュメントの以下の部分の記載が間違っています。

```
誤：gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com
正：gap: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com
```

Content Security Policyについては[このページ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives)などを参考にされると良いかと思います。
簡単に説明すると`default-src`ディレクティブに対して`source-list`を指定します。
この`source-list`に指定する形式として、以下があります。

- http形式のURI
- 特定のキーワード（`'none'`/`'self'`/`'unsafe-inline'`など）
- `Data`形式（`data:`/`blob:`/`filesystem:`など)

エラー内容は「`default-src`ディレクティブに含まれる`gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com`は不正です。」と説明しています。
つまり`gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com`という一連の文字列は、`source-list`に指定する形式として不正ということです。

前述の通り、`gap:` `cdvfile:` `https://ssl.gstatic.com`をそれぞれ個別に指定することでエラーは発生しなくなると思います。

---

補足

２個目のエラーについてもエラー内容の通りです。
Content Security Policyには`default-src`ディレクティブはありますが、`default-src'self'`ディレクティブはありません。

Comment: 詳しい説明をありがとうございます。
投稿前に試したことがあるのですが、スペースで区切ってもエラーが出力します。
エラーの内容は、
`Refused to load the script 'https://debug.monaca.mobi/target/target-script-min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`
このような内容になります。
文法に間違いは無いと思っていますので、他の要因（OSが5.0.1だから？）もあるのではと色々調査している所です。

Comment: `'https://debug.monaca.mobi/target/target-script-min.js' `を読み込もうとして、`script-src`でこれを許可していないので読み込めなかったというエラーに見えます。Content Security Policyは正常に動作してエラーを出してくれています。`'https://debug.monaca.mobi/target/target-script-min.js' `を読み込まないようにするか、Content Security Policyの`script-src`または`default-src`で読み込めるように指定するか、のどちらか選択してください。

Comment: 回答や添付先の資料を見て、以下の通り組み直したところ、ようやくエラーが出なくなりました。`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com cdvfile: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline>`defaultに記入しても問題なさそうなのですが、原因は未だに解明できず・・・エラーもなく動作を確認したため、閉めたいと思います。長々とおつきあいいただき、ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m